# Saving argv[1] to a char* variable causes seg fault when passed to separate function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, argv, c-strings, readdir

I'm trying to rewrite a stripped down version of the "ls" command in C. I originally had everything being done in my `main()` which worked fine and resulted in no seg faults. Literally all I did was copy and paste the bulk of my main into a new function, which I called `into_array()` (to do the actual saving the directory entries into my own self-made `file_info` structs to be analyzed later on). Now, when I try to run it sunny-day code -- just `a.out /home` which is supposed to sort and print the names, I get the full sorted list, followed by a seg fault, and since the only thing I changed was the direct use of `argv[1]` to the use of a `char *pathname`, I'm assuming it has something to do with that. Below is the code:

```
void into_array (char *arg)
{
    //asume correct input, default
    DIR *myDIR;
    struct dirent *mydirent;
    struct stat *mystat;

    myDIR = opendir(arg);
    int count = 0;

    while ((mydirent = readdir(myDIR)) != NULL)
    {
        count++;
    }

    rewinddir(myDIR);

    struct file_info **file_info_array = malloc(sizeof(struct file_info*)*count);
    int i = 0;
    while ((mydirent = readdir(myDIR)) != NULL)
    {
            stat(arg, mystat);
            file_info_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct file_info));
            struct file_info *file_i = info_store(mydirent, mystat, 's');
            file_info_array[i] = file_i;
            i++;
    }

    file_info_array[i] = NULL;
    int is_closed = closedir(myDIR);

    send_to_sort(file_info_array, 'n');
    print(file_info_array);
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    into_array(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the segfault? And why have you not protected against "finger trouble" by checking `argc` in `main()`? For all we know, you forget to run the program with an argument.

Answer (score 3):

This can't work:

```
struct stat *mystat;
 ...

stat(arg, mystat)
```

`stat` requires a pointer to storage where it can store the result, `mystat` isn't initialized. Easiest is to just do

```
struct stat mystat;
stat(arg, &mystat)
```

You're writing past your array with `file_info_array[i] = NULL;`. You haven't allocated storage for that last element, you should allocate storage for `count + 1` elements if you need the last element to be a NULL pointer.

Other things you need to do, otherwise you're setting yourself up to not be able to figure out what happens when your code fails:

- opendir() can fail, make sure you check that it succeeds.
- stat() can fail, make sure you check that it succeeds.
- malloc() can fail, make sure you check that it succeeds.
- Someone might not pass an argument to your program, check for that.
- There's a chance there's equally many errors in your other functions, you should audit those too.

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you! I just don't understand why, if I declare `mystat` as a pointer to a stat struct, `stat(arg, mystat)` wouldn't work -- I'm giving it a pointer, here, no?

Comment: Also yes I know I've written an error header file that I'll implement later. I just wanted to get my sunny day code working.

Comment: @jiccan Yes, you gave it a pointer, but where did that pointer point ? Can stat() store the result there ? (No it can't, the pointer isn't initailzied, you don't know where it points, which might be nowhere in particular)

Comment: @jiccan as stated in the answer, your `mystat` does not point to anything relevant.

Comment: Fixed the allocation, but that alone didn't get rid of the seg fault. Two questions: one, why did it work, then, when my `into_array()` function didn't exist and everything was just in `main()`? And two, -- I know this is a stupid question but I really am not comfortable with C at this point in time -- what exactly does the `&` do when placed in front of a non-pointer variable?

Comment: Pointer errors like this don't always cause the program to crash. It's undefined behavior, so anything can happen. The `&` before a variable is the "address of" operator -- it returns a pointer to the memory of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

That your original program did not segfault does not prove that it was wholly correct.  If it exhibits undefined behavior, then that behavior can turn out to be exactly the behavior you hoped and expected, but you can't rely on that being the same from run to run, much less after you modify the code (without resolving the UB).

Your program contains calls to several functions whose definitions you do not provide.  Any of those might invoke UB.  The function you did provide, however, certainly *does* invoke UB: it writes past the end of dynamic array `file_info_array`, because you allocate exactly enough space for all the entries, but not for the NULL at the end.

As @nos first observed, you also have a problem related to variable `mystat`, and you code very optimistically, assuming the program arguments are correct and that none of your function calls fail.

Comment: Oh, okay. So this should fix that, right?: `struct file_info **file_info_array = malloc(sizeof(struct file_info*)*(count+1))`

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier, I've already more or less written the checks -- they'll be added later. Right now, I'm testing it with 100% accurate inputs. Having so many error checks was just cluttering my code and making it harder to read because it was so long. But yes, I'm trying to understand the `stat` problem. Online, I've seen it declared as a pointer so I'm still confused as to why it worked for them and doesn't seem to work for me, here.

Comment: yes, you need just one more slot in `file_info_array` than you did have.